# What's the lib do I need for implements XMPP over websocket

Tags: websocket, xmpp

What's the lib do I need for implements XMPP over websocket?

(https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-xmpp-websocket-10)

Comment: client? server? both?

Comment: You have just asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985102/give-me-some-how-to-and-quick-start-and-libs-for-xmpp-over-websocket), which was instantly closed. Did you read the close reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For everyone who search such info - I found the answer:

The solution for server is openfire (there is implementation on websocket)

for client - strophe.js.  On this js lib already created "converse.js" - it implements many goods for client.